# How to properly setup a MVC application like CakePHP and Laravel?

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-5, cakephp-3.0, solid-principles

I'm trying to understand the benefits of fat models and skinny controllers notion. I've read many articles so far and below are my questions. Please answer the questions considering what's the best approach in CakePHP 3 and laravel 5.2.

1) Does following fat models/keeping the business logic inside controllers notion simply means never to use the ORM methods like find, save, etc inside the controllers.

2) Why do all the examples in cakephp and laravel documentation show queries inside controllers only and not inside the custom model functions which should be called in controllers.

3) There are many patterns and architectures like datamapper, repository, active record. Which one is best for a large scale enterprise applications. Is it better to go with Doctrine in such case rather than the bundled ORM's ?

4) What if i need to call another model inside a custom model function. Is that okay? if not then what should be the best approach in such case. Please explain with an example like cakephp doc uses blog,user, comments, etc

Thanks.

Comment: I don't use PHP, but to answer the first question:  not exactly, although that'll get you a good portion of the way there.

Comment: @Casey can you provide an example to describe what else is not covered by simply not using the ORM inside the controllers ?

Comment: This is not a question for SO. Post it at http://discourse.cakephp.org/

Comment: This question is not cakephp specific and not suitable for discourse.cakephp.org either. It is a general question with a part of it requiring solution details specific to laravel and cakephp amongst others.

Comment: @abansal Mapping from ORM objects to a view model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking some pretty broad questions here so expect broad answers. To give you some insight from my experiences:

1. No, there are many cases where the logic is simple enough or not directly bound to data that the business logic can be contained in a controller method. That being said, I like to treat controllers as the roadway between two endpoints; i.e. i may pick up data along the way but I try not to manipulate data in a controller, merely serve it to a view or to a repository to be updated.
2. Simplicity? It's best not to introduce too many concepts into one example. The same principle applies to programming, abstract and keep things simple.
3. I've used the repository pattern, active record and doctrine all in projects. It's the right tool for the right job.
4. I try to keep direct model access as abstracted as possible. Your underlying  storage schema may change at any point and it's best not to rely on any sort of "structure" being there.

Comment: The business logic *can* be contained in the controller method no matter how complex it is.  In my opinion, however, it is best to simply always avoid it, rather than sometimes putting it there and sometimes somewhere else.

Comment: @Casey That's more or less the point I'm trying to make. Keep things separated from the controller as much as possible, but if its a few lines of code doing something unique, a controller method is just as appropriate a place as any.

Comment: Yeah, but what I'm saying is that I prefer to always make it separate, even if it's just a few lines.  My reasoning is this:  1) it makes it easier to navigate the code and find it again if you're always consistent, since you don't need special knowledge about how complex the method was 2) it's too subjective deciding what's "simple" and what isn't 3) the business logic has a way of becoming more complex than it started 4) just better separation of concerns.

Comment: #1 @btl and together have answered the first part of the question but rest of the parts are still not properly answered.

Comment: #2 simplicity cannot be an excuse for providing examples of anti patterns exclusively and not a single one on how it should be done. Some may argue its not frameworks job to teach MVC but they they should not provide bad examples either. Maybe only cakePHP developers can answer this.

Comment: #3 everybody knows its about right tool for the right job. But the question was which tool to use and how to decide which is the right tool. What factors to consider. What are the strength and weaknesses of each pattern

Comment: #4 Its good what you do but the question is what to do if you need data from another model to make business logic calculations. In that case is it okay to access model x from a custom function in model y. Or some other method should be used.